# How to pass in variable from database | Node | Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I need to pass a variable into a ejs template file. I have a routes.js file in my /routes directory, then I have a /views and a /views/partials. How do I pass variable data into this?

I require the template files in the correct spots and need to do something along the lines of <%= company.name %> inserted into a profile.

My /test route is this:

```
// dashboard test
  app.get('/dashboard/test',
    setRender('dashboard/test'),
    setRedirect({auth:'/'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    dashboard.getDefault);
```

Comment: Have you read [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes in the first line of my question I mentioned ejs which is a very common template engine. So yes I am using the template engine ejs.

Answer (score 0):

What is `setRender()`?  What is `setRedirect()`?  What is `isAuthenticated` Where are they defined?  I'm assuming `isAuthenticated` is some middleware function to deal with authentication.

I think you need to read [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).  Your code should look more like this:

```
// Set template engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Set where views are located
app.set("views", "dashboard");

// Handle request after sending it through "isAuthenticated" middleware function
app.get("/dashboard/test", isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
    // Render the "test" template and give it the following data
    res.render("test", {
        company: {
            name: "SOME COMPANY NAME"
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: The routes are coming from a boilerplate I am using, I truly have no damm clue how half it works. I have tried adding on a arrow function (which normally works with express and ejs) but it doesn't work far as I can tell.